# wpf databinding: update targets in different views via datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, multilingual

I'm trying to implement a language selection system for my modernui wpf application. When language is switched from the combobox this change would be propagated to all of the application controls by means of databinding. 
I've built the skeleton as follows:

- languages are objects collected in a List
- strings and their counterparts are stored in a static dictionary
- data for binding is fetched by a Translation object
- views have binding to the datacontext which is based on language framework

Below is the stripped down version of the functionalty and link to the sample vs2013 project. I tried INotify.. without success, I could only manage to update the binding target by resetting datacontext of the view (page1.xaml). Unfortunately couldn't update target on the other view (home.xaml). Question comes down to: "How to update all targets in all views at the same time?"
I'll appreciate any help and suggestions to setup a proper binding structure.

download sample project: http://goo.gl/yjSsKm

home.xaml

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel MinWidth="200">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding home_text_1}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

page1.xaml

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel MinWidth="200">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding page1_text_1}"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbox_lang" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,50,0,0" SelectionChanged="cbox_lang_SelectionChanged"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using DynamicDataBinding.Pages;
using FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Controls;

namespace DynamicDataBinding
{
    public partial class MainWindow : ModernWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Language lang_1 = new Language("Language 1");
            Language lang_2 = new Language("Language 2");
            Global.availableLanguages.Add(lang_1);
            Global.availableLanguages.Add(lang_2);
            Global.currentLanguage = lang_1;
            Global.currentLanguage.set();
        }
    }
}
```

page1.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DynamicDataBinding.Pages
{
    public partial class Page1 : UserControl
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (Language lang in Global.availableLanguages) 
            {
                cbox_lang.Items.Add(lang.Name);
            }
            cbox_lang.SelectedItem = Global.currentLanguage.Name;
            this.DataContext = Global.currentLanguage.FrameWork;
        }

        private void cbox_lang_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbox_lang.SelectedItem.ToString() != Global.currentLanguage.Name)
            {
                string selectedLanguage = cbox_lang.SelectedItem.ToString();
                Global.currentLanguage = Global.availableLanguages.Find(lang => lang.Name == selectedLanguage);
                Global.currentLanguage.set();
                DataContext = null;
                DataContext = Global.currentLanguage.FrameWork;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Global
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public static List<Language> availableLanguages = new List<Language>();
        public static Language currentLanguage;
    }

    public class Language
    {
        public string Name;
        public Translation FrameWork; 

        public Language(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public void set()
        {
            Global.dictionary.Clear();
            if (Global.currentLanguage.Name == "Language 1")
            {
                Global.dictionary.Add("home_content_1", "Content For Home in Language 1");
                Global.dictionary.Add("page1_content_1", "Content For Page1 in Language 1");
            }
            else if (Global.currentLanguage.Name == "Language 2")
            {
                Global.dictionary.Add("home_content_1", "Different Content For Home in Language 2");
                Global.dictionary.Add("page1_content_1", "Different Content For Page1 in Language 2");
            }
            FrameWork = new Translation();
        }
    }

    public class Translation
    {
        public string home_text_1 { get { return Global.dictionary["home_content_1"]; } }
        public string page1_text_1 { get { return Global.dictionary["page1_content_1"]; } }
    }
}
```

home.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace DynamicDataBinding.Pages
{
    public partial class Home : UserControl
    {
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = Global.currentLanguage.FrameWork;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the looks of your code I will encourage you to look at the [MvvM tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level).

Comment: I'm aware that this structure do not correspond well to the mvvm framework. I'm still learning and I'll appreciate all suggestions to fix the inefficient mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day (eventually) I figured out that there is no need to deal with datacontext. Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged handles all of the target updates if it is setup properly. Furthermore use of a dictionary is not suitable to hold data if binding is in question. Below is the corrected version of the code:

page1.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DynamicDataBinding.Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Page1 : UserControl
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (Language lang in Global.availableLanguages) 
            {
                cbox_lang.Items.Add(lang.Name);
            }
            cbox_lang.SelectedItem = Global.currentLanguage.Name;
            this.DataContext = Global.FrameWork;
        }

        private void cbox_lang_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbox_lang.SelectedItem.ToString() != Global.currentLanguage.Name)
            {
                string selectedLanguage = cbox_lang.SelectedItem.ToString();
                Global.currentLanguage = Global.availableLanguages.Find(lang => lang.Name == selectedLanguage);
                Global.currentLanguage.set();
                DataContext = null;
                DataContext = Global.FrameWork;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Global
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public static List<Language> availableLanguages = new List<Language>();
        public static Language currentLanguage;
        public static Translation FrameWork = new Translation();
    }

    public class Language
    {

        public string Name;
        public Language(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public void set()
        {
            Global.dictionary.Clear();
            if (Global.currentLanguage.Name == "Language 1")
            {
                Global.FrameWork.home_text_1 = "Content For Home in Language 1";
                Global.FrameWork.page1_text_1 = "Content For Home in Language 1";

            }
            else if (Global.currentLanguage.Name == "Language 2")
            {
                Global.FrameWork.home_text_1 = "Different Content For Home in Language 2";
                Global.FrameWork.page1_text_1 = "Different Content For Home in Language 2";
            }
        }
    }

    public class Translation : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private string _home_text_1;
        private string _page1_text_1;

        public string home_text_1 { get {return _home_text_1;} set { _home_text_1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("home_text_1"); }}
        public string page1_text_1 { get {return _page1_text_1;} set { _page1_text_1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("page1_text_1");}}
    }
}
```